# jQuery .css("color") returns rgb() on FF/Chrome, returns Hex on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Forever trying to fix IE CSS calculation issues, but I didn't expect to see this.

I'm trying to retrieve the color value from an element in HTML, and I don't mind what format it is returned in as long as it's consistent across all browsers. So why would `$(".elem").css("color")` return RGB of Firefox and Chrome, but return Hex on IE and Edge?

And how can I stop it doing this? Is there a way to specify the return format?

Comment: The logic in the duplicate is for the `background-color`, but is the same for `color` too

Comment: Investigating this as a solution, but it doesn't explain why MS still can't make browsers that work.

Comment: I think we're destined to never figure that one out :D

Comment: Cheers for setting duplicate, got the answer I needed and I'm now only working with hex values.

Comment: Glad it helped :)